# Why is are the images being cut off?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui

The images in my 'tiles' are being cut off at the sides. I am trying to create a tile for each 'product' that displays an image, name and subtitle. Everything now works as it should besides the image. This is because the images on the tiles are being cut off at the sides.

The view for the ContentView is as follows:

```
     ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                    
                    Spacer()
                    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 15), count: 2),spacing: 10){
                        
                        ForEach(HomeModel.filteredProduct){product in
                            
                            // Product View...
                            
                                
                                ProductView(productData: product)
                                .background(.white)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        
                                        withAnimation(.easeIn){
                                            
                                            selectedProduct = charity
                                            show.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.top,10)
                })
                .padding(.top, 20)
```

And the ProductView code is as follows:

```
    var body: some View {
    
        
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                
                WebImage(url: URL(string: productData.product_image))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 160, height: 225)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .clipped()
                    .padding(5)
               
            Text(productData.product_name)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
            
                
            Text(productData.product_type)
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .padding()
        }
}
```

Here is an image showing what is meant by 'the tile is cutting it off':

[image: Tile image]

As you can see in the photo, the image is not all included because it doesn't fit in the tile. This needs to be resized.

Comment: Try using the `.clipped()` and '.clipShape()' modifiers.

Comment: @CharlieReeder I haven't managed to get those modifiers to work

Answer (score 2):

The first issue here would be the `.contentMode` modifier it needs to be set to fill. If you have an image where the width is larger then the height but you set the frame at a different aspect ratio you will see a white space above and below the image.

But there were other problems too. You need to clip an image with the `.clipped()` modifier after you set its frame, else it will overflow the frame. Why all those `ZStacks`? I cannot see any purpose of adding a `ZStack` with only one child.

---

### BUT:

As your code is not reproducible i had to add or remove several things to make it work. So you need to adopt this to your code.

---

### Solution:

```
struct ContentView: View{
    
    @State private var products: [ProductData] = [ProductData(product_name: "test", product_details: "test"), ProductData(product_name: "test2", product_details: "test2"), ProductData(product_name: "test3", product_details: "test3")]
    @State private var show = false
    @State private var selectedProduct: ProductData?
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
            Spacer()
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 15), count: 2),spacing: 10){
                
                ForEach(products){product in
                    // Product View...
                    ProductView(productData: product)
                        .background(.white)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.easeIn){
                                selectedProduct = product
                                show.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
                .padding()
                .padding(.top,10)
        })
        .padding(.top, 20)
    }
}

struct ProductData: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var product_name: String
    var product_details: String
}


struct ProductView: View{
    var productData: ProductData
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            Image("test")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 160, height: 225)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .clipped()
                .padding(5)
            
            Text(productData.product_name)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
            
            Text(productData.product_details)
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .padding()
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

### Outcome:

[image: Outcome]

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I am still getting the issue of parts of the images being cut off though. The sides of the images have been cut off by the tile.

Comment: @Mxyb there could be multiple reason for that. Please update your question to contain the changed code and provide an image showing your current state and what you want to achieve. Because i don´t know what `The sides of the images have been cut off by the tile` means.

Comment: @Mxyb if you realy want the whole image in here you could get rid of the `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` modifier but this would distort the image. Try this blog entry https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-adjust-the-way-an-image-is-fitted-to-its-space

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look. I have edited the question